# ITK in C# .NET Application

Tags: c#, itk

I used ImageToVTKImageFilter in `C++` application for converting my vtk image to itk.

I wanted to implement this concept in my c# .net application. I used ActiViz.NET for my VTK part.

For ITK in c#, wrapITK, ManagedITK and simpleITK options are available but these are low versions and these are not having ItkVtkGlue.

**Question**: How do I use ITK or how can I implement ItkVtkGlue in my .NET C# application?

Are there any other options are available to use ITK in C# .NET?

Answer (score 3):

`C#` is not supported by `ITK`'s wrapping infrastructure, and that has been [so](https://itk.org/pipermail/insight-users/2014-January/049519.html) for quite a while. A simplified variant of `ITK`, [`SimpleITK`](https://itk.org/Wiki/SimpleITK/GettingStarted#C.23_binary_files), has support for `C#` among other languages.

**Edit:** Both `ITK` and `SimpleITK` have [ImportImageFilter](https://itk.org/SimpleITKDoxygen/html/classitk_1_1simple_1_1ImportImageFilter.html). `ITKVTKGlue` uses that filter internally. Using that filter directly requires more code, but can be done without `ITKVTKGlue` module.

Comment: ItkVtkGlue is not in SimpleITK, then how can i do?